# Is abortion okay if it is medically necessary?

Tags: abortion, ethics

I'm sure that most of us agree that abortion is sinful and certainly not okay...*most of the time*. However, I'm thinking of two rare circumstances that *may* be exceptions.

1. The mother would die but the baby would (probably) live if an abortion is not performed.
2. The mother AND the (still-living) baby would die if an abortion is not performed.

Does the Bible (or some other significant work) provide any perspective on these questions?

Comment: Most of us.  Count me in the minority.  Not that I'm surprised... :-P  (No, abortion is not okay per se... everyone should do their utmost to avert it.  But not by law, and not by force.)

Comment: Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource for your convenience: [Question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)

Comment: @fredsbend: I just went ahead and closed it. It's really old, and I *could* narrow it down, but then the answers would be mismatched.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman I figured you'd do that anyway. BTW, that's just my cookie cutter comment. I know you know the site guidelines. I put it there for other users to see site policy in action.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a difficult topic. Some biblical references would help to understand how God views an unborn child:

God views the life of a child as precious even during the very early stages of development after conception:

**Psalms 139:13-16**

> For you created my inmost being;    **you knit me together in my
>   mother’s womb**. 14 I praise you because I am fearfully and wonderfully
>   made;    your works are wonderful,    I know that full well. 15 My
>   frame was not hidden from you    when I was made in the secret place, 
>   when I was woven together in the depths of the earth. 16 **Your eyes saw
>   my unformed body;    all the days ordained for me were written in your
>   book    before one of them came to be.**

God stated that a person would be called to account for injury to an unborn child:

**Exodus 21:22,23**

> If people are fighting and hit a pregnant woman and she gives birth
>   prematurely[a] but there is no serious injury, the offender must be
>   fined whatever the woman’s husband demands and the court allows.

It's a very serious sin to willfully take a human life for any reason not authorized by God:

**Genesis 9:6**

> Whoever sheds human blood,    by humans shall their blood be shed; for
>   in the image of God    has God made mankind.

**Exodus 20:13**

> “You must not murder.”

So the *life* of a child is very valuable in God's eyes. If a medical decision *must* be taken between mother's or child's life, this is up to the couple. If the doctors inform the parents that the child will be born with medical problems, this is no reason to murder the child.

Comment: Psalms: this is usually interpreted... this way.  But I disagree.  The question is: *when* does life start?  "You knit" me means I'm not finished.  I'm... being made.  So, am I, or am I not yet?  Inconclusive.  Exodus... wow, how does that relate to abortion?  Not at all.  Genesis 9:6?  Sure... the bible is full of pacifists, right?  Obviously not.  So why relate Gen 9:6 to abortion?  Exodus... yeah, same as for Genesis.

Comment: @Jürgen A. Erhard - what makes "you knit" a case of "being made", rather than have been made?

Comment: I think the relevant question when asking "when does life begin?" is to ask "what changes in the nature of the child from the minute before the child is born to the minute after?" The full answer is too long for a comment, but the nutshell answer is: Age, location, and dependence. But none of those things affect person-hood. A friend of mine (sarcastically) advocates abortion rights up to the age of 4. Because just as much changes between the ages of 3 and 4 as between pre-birth and birth. But by the age of 4, parents will be much more educated as to whether they wish to be parents!

Comment: I think you should add verse 23 to Ex.21 "But if there is serious injury, you are to take life for life, 24 eye for eye, tooth for tooth, hand for hand, foot for foot, 25 burn for burn, wound for wound, bruise for bruise."

Comment: Exodus 21 says that killing an unborn child is a civil tort, not criminal law (in modern terms).  If killing an unborn child was murder, the law would specify the death penalty.  Clearly, in this passage, Fetal killing is a crime against property, not a crime against life.

Comment: @chris the law specified the death penalty according to Exodus 21:23

Comment: @sotiris No, not for the death of the unborn.  The scripture is unequivocal on this point. Kill an unborn, and you pay a fine.  It's specified with the predicate "If there is any other injury..." and "life for life," I take to mean as punishment of equal injury, or Eye for an Eye.

Comment: @chris the word "but" in the beginning of verse 23 shows that the writer continues to talk for an unborn child. Nowhere it says that if you kill an unborn "you pay a fine" instead talks for "life for life" http://bible.cc/exodus/21-23.htm

Comment: It's actually due to different translations.  Mine says "she has a miscarriage." -- Which changes the meaning completely.

Comment: "And if men struggle with each other and strike a woman with child so that she has a miscarriage, yet there is no further injury, he shall surely be fined as the woman's husband may demand of him; and he shall pay as the judges decide"  -- this goes beyond our abilities to decipher.  We need the Judaic scholars now.

Comment: I asked the translation question on Judaism.  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11203/translation-issue-exodus-21/11205#11205

Answer (score 7):

No, and this isn't surprising considering the state of medical knowledge in Old Testament times. (And it really hadn't advanced all that much by NT times.)  There was no way to diagnose that carrying a pregnancy to term would put the mother's life in danger, the way we can today with electric-powered technologies such as ultrasound imaging.

Answer (score 5):

Both situations described illustrate a lack of faith in God. I would imagine that a Christian pondering the situation would either (please pardon the generalizations)

- not believe that God knows or is able to save their lives or,
- not believe that the outcome of carrying the baby to term would ultimately be the best outcome for for both the baby and mother.

> **Romans 8:28** (NIV)
>   And we know that in all things God works for the good of those who love him, who have been called according to his purpose.

Comment: I would change your first bullet point to "not believe that God knows what's best"--God may use the death of the mother and/or child for His glory.

Comment: @Filmy - I'm interested to know: how?

Comment: Great. So why bother taking medicine? Perhaps God may use the death of faith healers' customer for his glory. So far it doesn't work that way though.

Comment: @JimThio Abstaining from medicine is not a comparable scenario because taking medicine is not sinful. Murder, on the other hand, is sinful. It is my belief and the belief of many Christians that a fetus is a human being with a soul (See other answers). Therefore, terminating the pregnancy is murder. So in this situation, the most important thing for the parents is to obey God's commands as far as it depends on them and **trust** that God has an overall plan. Since taking medicine is not a sin in itself, there is no reason why a sick person should turn from it.